# Google didn't update the search results after changing a URL with a permanent redirect

Tags: seo, htaccess, url, 301-redirect

I have a simple personal webpage which I use to list my publications and link the corresponding PDFs (I work in academia). Until now, this webpage was hosted by my university:

```
http(s)://myuniversitydomain.example/~myusername
```

and it was very well ranked on Google (searching for either my name or one of my articles would print my webpage first). My public folder contains (among other things):

- an *index.html* file (my personal webpage);
- a folder *documents* containing the PDF files which are linked on my webpage.

For some reason I had to move it to another location (on some server hosted by another institution):

```
https://myusername.domain.example
```

So I added a *.htaccess* file at the root of my old public folder, containing the following redirection:

```
RedirectPermanent /~myusername https://myusername.domain.example
```

The redirections (for the webpage or the PDF files) work well. Moreover, I checked (using Safari's web inspector) that the university server responded with HTTP 301.

The problem now is that Google did not change the URL in the search results. Using Google Search Console, I realized that the new URL had been excluded because they were considered duplicate. So I added a canonical link to my webpage. I also asked Google to reindex the new URL and the old one.

I am surprised that Google has not figured out yet that the old URLs (of the webpage and the PDF files) should be replaced by the new ones... Am I doing something wrong? How can I ensure that Google will eventually do the replacement and transfer the ranking?

Comment: I expect its just a matter of waiting.

Comment: "Google did not change the URL in the search results." - For this are you searching using the same _organic_ method as mentioned above: "searching for either my name or one of my articles"? Or using a `site:` search?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your 301 redirect is in place properly, it is definitely just a matter of waiting.

The old result will be replaced by the new result, it may just take several weeks. In the mean time, users who click the old search result should be sent to the new URL by the 301 (click on your google search results yourself to double check that this is the case).